# iPhone backup switches to "This Computer" in iTunes and I want it to back up to iCloud

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, backup

When I open iTunes and click on my phone icon, all of my settings look good except for backups which is set to "This Computer." I check off iCloud and click "Apply" and it instantly switches back to "This Computer." I'm signed into iCloud on the phone and the computer with the same account. I have plenty of space in iCloud as well so that shouldn't be a problem. Why does it switch and how can I get it to stick to iCloud?

[image: iTunes screen after clicking apply to apply the settings.]

Comment: Looking at that, it would appear it has never backed up to iCloud. The date of the last cloud backup ought to also be below 'latest backup'. You also really ought to have local backups encrypted, otherwise it won't save any security data. Check your phone has it enabled. Settings>your name>iCloud>iCloud Backup

Comment: On my phone, it says the last backup was yesterday at 10:01pm and the iCloud switch is on so it is backing up to the cloud. It is just that iTunes doesn't recognize that for some reason.

Comment: Ah, OK. Sorry, I've no idea then. Wish you luck :)